# How to print next characters after a pattern search in Unix?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have bunch of files in a folder, need to search with the keywords 'PO' and SUPP to print the next chars in a output file. Please help.

file 1:

```
PO 0962690   SUPP  212055    20180820000000   8709384 PO 0962693   SUPP  212059    20180820000000   8709384 ACDEF 123456 85 PO 123456
```

file 2:

```
PO 0962709   SUPP  1527 20180820000000   8709403
```

Expected Output:

```
0962690,212055
0962693,212059
123456,
0962709,1527
```

Comment: If a `SUPP` does appear, does it always come immediately after `PO <digits>`?

Comment: No.. It is not like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -hPo '\bPO\s+\d+(\s+SUPP\s+\d+)?' file* | awk -v OFS=, '{print $2,$4}'
```

or (even) more cryptically

```
perl -nE 's/\bPO\s+(\d+)(?:\s+SUPP\s+(\d+))?/say "$1,$2"/ge' file
```

Comment: It is working for most of the files, Failing for few cases where we have some prefix with the key word PO. Example.. RPO 8709384  EXPIREDPO 12548

Comment: That's what the `\b` is for